# what is the maximum theoretical density for qubits?

Tags: near-future, computers, quantum

What is the maximum amount of qubits that could be put in a cubed centimeter and still function? The technology level is near future, within the next 50 years.

bonus question:
how much computing power would a cubed centimeter of qubits packed to their maximum have?

people who are downvoting, please explain so that I can either remove or improve my question.

Comment: This is an excellent question.  The Bekenstein bound describes the absolute maximum data density possible, no matter the technology level.  I'd be interested to learn whether there is a limit when dealing strictly with qubits and current-ish technology.

Comment: Consider a [SanDisk Ultra Fit](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07857Y17V) flash drive (link goes to Amazon); packs more than 2,000,000,000,000 (classical) bits in a very very small package. Do you believe that 50 years ago anybody could have imagined such density for permanent memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Nobody has the slightest idea

50 years ago, IBM introduced the [System/370 Model 145](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/370_Model_145), the first IBM computer to use semiconductor memory for its main memory instead of magnetic core memory.  It had 512 KB of memory.  It filled a small room.

A microSD card is the size of your fingernail, and they can hold at least [1 TB](https://www.theverge.com/2019/5/15/18626729/sandisks-1tb-microsd-card-available-b-h-photo-amazon-price).  That's 2,000,000 times the storage capacity, and the storage density is orders of magnitude higher.

50 years is an age in computer technology.  When the writers of Star Trek designed their communicators (in 1966), they were trying to envision a technology from thousands of years in the future.  A decade old smartphone now makes them look obsolete.

The technology for quantum computing is in its infancy.  We have no basis for guessing what the theoretical limits are, or how long it will take until we start to reach them.  It could be that we reach terabyte storage in 20 years, or a century, or never at all.  Nobody knows.

Comment: Excellent answer (also probably not very satisfying to OP). Just as added info, current qubits are roughly 1m^3 each, just to get an order of magnitude for what is possible today.

Comment: @quarague  1m^3? Um... https://www.dwavesys.com/d-wave-two-system  D-Wave puts 2000 q-bits on a chip, and the whole system uses up only a few cubic meters.

Comment: @puppetsock This depends on whether you see the D-Wave as a full quantum computer or whether it is just a special purpose machine that uses a particular quantum mechanics effect to solve a very specific problem. To me it is the latter and actual quantum bits currently exist only in few lab setups in the world. IIRC the record is help by google with 20 something qbits or so.